# c++ - Calling template funсtion without <'typename'>

Tags: c++, templates

I'm creating doubly linked list which has different types with template.

here is header and main code.

```
#ifndef UNV_LIST
#define UNV_LIST
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

class node_base{
    public:
        node_base *next;
        node_base *prev;
        node_base () { next = 0; prev = 0; }
        virtual int get_node_size () = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class node : public node_base{
    public:
        T data;
        node (const T& val) : data(val) {}
        virtual int get_node_size () { return sizeof (data); }
        T getData () { return data; }
};

class unvlist{
        node_base *head;
    public:
        int len;
        unvlist ();
        template <typename T> unvlist (const T* arr, int n);
        ~unvlist ();

        template <typename T> void set (int n, const T& val);
        template <typename T> T get (int n);
        template <typename T> T insert (int n, const T& val);
        void erase (int n);
        int size ();
        void pop_back ();
        void pop_front ();
        template <typename T> void push_back (const T& val);
        template <typename T> void push_front (const T& val);
};

unvlist :: unvlist (){
    head = 0;
    len = 0;
}

/* I want to use this function without <> */
template <typename T>
T unvlist :: get (int n){
    T retval;

    if (n >= len || n < 0){
        cout << "'In unvlist::get'-> Out of Bound!!!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if (n >= 0){
        node_base *h = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { h = h->next; }
        retval = static_cast<node<T>*>(h)->getData ();
        cout << retval << endl;
    }
    return retval;
}

template <typename T>
void unvlist :: push_back (const T& val){
    node_base *n = new node<T> (val);

    if (head == NULL){
        head = n;
        len++;
    }else{
        node_base *h = head;
        while (h->next != NULL) { h = h->next; }
        h->next = n;
        n->prev = h;
        len++;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void unvlist :: push_front (const T& val){
    node_base *n = new node<T> (val);

    if (head == NULL){
        head = n;
        len++;
    }else{
        head->prev = n;
        n->next = head;
        head = n;
        len++;
    }
}

#endif
```

and main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "unvlist.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main (){
    unvlist *l1 = new unvlist ();

    l1->push_back<string> ("aa");
    l1->push_back<char> ('A');
    l1->push_back<float> (1.2345);
    l1->push_front<int> (11);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        cout << l1->get (i) << endl;  //The problem is here...
    }   cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have to use the template function 'T get(int n)' without explicit <>.
When I compiled it, however, there are some errors...

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall  main.cpp  -o main
main.cpp: In function 'int main()'
main.cpp:16:21: error: no matching function for call to 'unvlist::get(int&)'
    cout << l1->get (i) << endl;
                      ^
main.cpp:16:21: note: candidate is:
In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
unvlist.hpp:44:27: note: template<class T> T unvlist::get(int)
   template <typename T> T get (int n);
                           ^
unvlist.hpp:44:27: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:16:21: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'
    cout << l1->get (i) << endl;
                      ^
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

'push_back' and 'push_front' function work well, but the problem is 'T get' function...
Is there a way to use 'T get' function without <>?

Comment: Shouldn't `unvlist` be templated instead.

Comment: The return type is a non deducible context, You may take it by reference to allow deduction and be able to call it without `<>`.

Comment: "I have to" Why? What do you expect it to return?

Comment: For the implied functionality, consider having a `virtual void print(std::ostream&) const;` function overridden appropriately for each `node<T>`, or even say `virtual operator std::string() const` to implicitly give you a printable representation (though that may be inefficient).

Comment: I agree with @Jarod42, you basically have a design flaw here. Templating the whole `unvlist` class would resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to derive the type of the template parameter T for the function

```
T unvlist::get(int i)
```

having just such a call  `list->get(3)`.

You could modify your getter as follows:

```
template <typename T>
void unvlist :: get (int n, T &retval){

    if (n >= len || n < 0){
        cout << "'In unvlist::get'-> Out of Bound!!!" << endl;
    }
    if (n >= 0){
        node_base *h = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { h = h->next; }
        retval = static_cast<node<T>*>(h)->getData ();
    }
}
```

And use with a priory known resulting type:

```
int main (){
    unvlist *l1 = new unvlist ();

    l1->push_back<string> ("aa");
    l1->push_back<string> ("A");

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        std::string result;  // we know std::string in advance
        l1->get(i, result);  // here compiler derives the T type correctly
        std::cout << result << std::endl;
    }   cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have to use the template function 'T get(int n)' without explicit <>

Well, you can't.

No arguments have anything to do with `T`, so the compiler has no way of knowing what you want it to do. It cannot read your mind.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of answering strictly what you've asked, no; the complier needs to know which version of get you're trying to call.

However you can achieve what it seems you're trying to do.
If get were to return node_base by reference (or pointer), and node_base had a virtual operator>> that was overridden for each node then the type problem goes away.

If you consider the node_base class to be an implementation detail that shouldn't be exposed, then you could create another class for get to return instead (again a base class with type specific derived classes).